# How to securely delete an OpenVPN connection profile

Tags: key-management, vpn

I store my OpenVPN profile (keys) in an encrypted drive but I run OpenVPN inside an OS that is not encrypted. When I finish my OpenVPN session and disconnect, the  connection profiles are still there (until I delete them). Is it safe to assume that my keys are not cached anywhere or do I need to go about securely deleting temp data?

Comment: Without knowing any details about your setup (e.g. which operating systems, how do you encrypt/mount your devices) we can't possibly tell you anything definitive. What about your OpenVPN profile itself. Normally it is wise to encrypt your private key, so whether or not the files end up being cached shouldn't matter. I would guess that OpenVPN is handling keys correctly, e.g. removing them from memory once they are no longer needed. The `persist-key` option is an indicator for that. So as long as you trust your unencrypted host, you are **probably** safe.

Comment: The key is encrypted itself, I have to enter a password each time I connect